# Issue with Groups Parameter in Testng.xml

Tags: testng

I am creating a testng.xml file to run my test methods belonging to a group "Sanity" from different classes. Classes are under different packages.

**Issue**: Testng is running all test method belonging to the group mentioned in XML, But the executive order is not correct, All priority with 1 from different classes are run first. Can we do something so that all test methods of a particular class are run first and so on?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
        <listeners>
            <listener class-name="com.TestngListeners" />
        </listeners>
        <test name="Test">
            <groups>
                <run>
                    <include name="Sanity"/>
                </run>
            </groups>
            <packages>
                <package name="com.tests.windows.*"></package>
                <package name="com.tests.server.*"></package>
            </packages>
        </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: This is the purpose of the `priority` attribute, i.e. changing the order of execution. Thus why do you set it ? If you remove it, all the tests methods of a given class will be executed in sequence.